# Convergence in mean from convergence in probability for vectors

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am in the situation where I would like to prove that  $E[X_n] \rightarrow E[X]$, where $X$ is a real-valued vector.

I proved that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ and it is clear by construction that $X_n$ is uniformly bounded (it belongs to a bounded domain independent of $n$) and positive in all of its element -- in fact, $X$ itself is a positive constant.

Now, if my understanding is correct, this would have been trivial had $X_n$ been a scalar: I would have used the uniform integrability (due to uniform bound) of $X_n$ to show convergence "in" and "of" mean. I am wondering if anything like that exists for vectors -- or what argument I can make to prove my point, if any at all.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A sequennce of real nubers converges to a number $a$ iff every subsequence has a  further subsequence which converges to $a$. There is a subsequence which converges almost surely and we get $E\|X_n-X\| \to 0$, bY DCT, along the subsequence.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Not following completely. There is a subsequence of $X_n$ that converges a.s. What is DCT though? Does a.s. convergence really guarantee $E|| X_n - X||$?

Comment: DCT is Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense. Thank you